# PhoneGap Build with Android Camera not firing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to get the camera working using phonegap build (I am very new to this). The problem is that nothing seems to be firing.

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_photo', function(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady(){
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {quality:50});
            function onSuccess(imageData){
                var image=document.getElementById('myImage');
                image.src='data:image/jpeg;base64,'+imageData;
            }
            function onFail(message){
                alert(message);
            }
    }
});
```

This has been modified from the Phoegap API pages.

`config.xml` includes the following lines:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, setting the quality to 20 fixed the problem for Android.
This only seems to be the issue on Android, for IOS you are safe using the quality value of 50.

```
var cameraParams = { 
    quality : 20,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
};
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onError, cameraParams);
```

Comment: thanks - will try this and get back to you - options appointment beckons :)

Comment: Still no luck although my camera seems to be playing up recently.

Comment: Try removing onclick event. Call getpicture on deviceready event. Maybe your onclick is not firing.

Comment: Still no luck - one thing that concerns me is that on an adobe tutorial they have a header link to a local `phonegap-1.1.0.js` file. I have downloaded the latest version of phonegap but can not find such file

Comment: phonegap is renamed to cordova and file you should include is located in \phonegap-2.5.0\phonegap-2.5.0\lib\android\cordova-2.5.0.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you included a link to the cordova.js? If you are using phonegap build you don't need to have the cordova file in your project, just add the following script tag to your header:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The phonegap build service adds the file automatically for you.

Comment: Just realized how old the thread is I suspect the problem has been solved, hopefully this helps someone else