# Phonegap getPicture not working

Tags: javascript, mobile, cordova

I am trying to choose a photo from the device library using PhoneGap.

```
function getFromLib()
navigator.notification.alert('Works!');
var options = {
        sourceType          :   Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
        destinationType     :   Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        limit               :   1,
        quality             :   40
    }
    navigator.camera.getPicture(captureSuccess, captureError, options);
```

}

The alert is firing onclick of the button inside the HTML. But that's all that happens, I have another function that captures an image using the camera which works flawlessly, but this one I'm stumped. Any help from someone who has done this a bit more than I have would be greatly appreciated!

I am testing using a Galaxy S3, just in case there is some strange device-specific bug anyone knows of.

Comment: Try decreasing image quality to 20. I had the same problem with Nexus 3. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659556/phongap-build-with-android-camera-not-firing/15659788#15659788)